# How do I create a menu for navigating to another file in Haskell

Tags: haskell, haskell-platform

I have three files (`Play.hs`, `Sudoku.hs` and `Nim.hs`), and each one of those files has a `main`.

I want to make a `main` in `Play.hs` to run one of those games (either Nim or Sudoku), like this:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
          putStrLn "1-Sudoku"
          putStrLn "2-Nim"
          putStrLn "choice----->"
          let x=getLine
          if x==1 then
              ....
          else 
              ...
```

Comment: This is a good tutorial on basic Haskell IO: [Simple input and output - Haskell Wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Simple_input_and_output)

Answer (score 4):

You may call the `main` value from other modules just fine, as long as add the line `module Nim where` to the top of `Nim.hs`, and similarly for `Sudoku.hs`.

Of course, if you have more than one `main` in scope, there will be ambiguity; but you can deal with ambiguity in the same way for `main` as you do for other names by qualifying them.

```
import Sudoku
import Nim

main = do
    ...
    if x == 1 then Sudoku.main else Nim.main
```

..and if you're in the interpreter, start your program with `Play.main`.

Comment: I don't know ,what can I do now !!

Comment: @SamiLi I'd love to help you, but I don't understand the problem yet. Could you expand a bit?

Comment: the problem that, I didn't work with module notion ,all my functions declared simply in Nim.hs and Sudoku.hs

Comment: the error is :   File name does not match module name :
saw :main
expected :Nim

Comment: @SamiLi You may add the line `module Nim where` to the top of `Nim.hs`, and similarly for `Sudoku.hs`.

Comment: @SamiLi Be more specific please. In what way? Are you getting an error? It works fr me. You'll need to specify `Play.main` rather than just saying `main` now that you have three in scope.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `import qualified` to resolve the ambiguity and simply call respective `main` from the game you need.

Make sure you've started `Sudoku.hs` with

```
module Sudoku where
```

and the same for `Nim.hs`; then you can do

```
import qualified Sudoku as S
import qualified Nim as N

main = 
    -- ....
    if x==1 then
        S.main
    else
        N.main
```